# Moved my Zend Framework app from Windows to Linux and recieve a Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception'

Tags: zend-framework

I have moved a relatively simple ZF app from a windows based server to a linux server and am recieving the following fatal error:

```
'Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'SiteDetail' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:/home/yourfran/public_html/customcutout/application/views/helpers/' in /usr/etc/Zend/library/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php:412 Stack trace: #0 /usr/etc/Zend/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(1182): Zend_Loader_PluginLoader->load('SiteDetail') #1 /usr/etc/Zend/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(618): Zend_View_Abstract->_getPlugin('helper', 'siteDetail') #2 /usr/etc/Zend/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(344): Zend_View_Abstract->getHelper('siteDetail') #3 /home/yourfran/public_html/customcutout/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml(28): Zend_View_Abstract->__call('siteDetail', Array) #4 /home/yourfran/public_html/customcutout/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml(28): Zend_View->siteDetail() #5 /usr/etc/Zend/library/Zend/View.php(108): include('/home/yourfran/...') #6 /usr/etc/Zend/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(888): Zend_View->_run('/hom in /usr/etc/Zend/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php on line 336
```

I have a view helper called Sitedetail (not SiteDetail), but nowhere in my code do I refer to it as *SiteDetail*, only lowercase *d*

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

Line 28, layout.phtml

```
<h1><?php echo $this->escape($this->siteDetail()->title); ?></h1>
```

FIXED: [HOW ? Like this..]

In my view helper (Sitedetail.php) I changed

```
public function siteDetail()
```

to

```
public function Sitedetail()
```

And then in my layout.phtml

```
<h1><?php echo $this->escape($this->siteDetail()->title); ?></h1>
<p><?php echo $this->escape($this->siteDetail()->strapline); ?></p>
```

to

```
<h1><?php echo $this->escape($this->Sitedetail()->title); ?></h1>
<p><?php echo $this->escape($this->Sitedetail()->strapline); ?></p>
```

Comment: /public_html/customcutout/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml(28): Can you paste code on line 28 of layout.phtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem some months ago. As you point out, the problem might be the case sensitiveness. The Windows filesystem is not case sensitive, but Linux definitively is.

Check the case in the filename of your helper file, it might be the cause.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thank, yes it was to do with the case sensiteveness. Answer is posted in my question.